# mysqli query from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one android webservice written in PHP MYSQL...There about three table which our developer is making query and putting that result in json. But I have issue when there no any row in other table than username returning empty. However username already available in one table. its making query like below

```
<?php

// Grab User submitted information
$UID = $_POST["UID"];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","myid","mypass", "mydb");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysqli_connect_error());
}

// mysql_select_db("tabdevel_yourdb",$con);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT l.username, 
                                    q.quote_id,q.status,q.credit,q.QOD,
                                    w.Total,w.Completed,w.Withdrawl,w.Credit 
                                    From quotes q, 
                                        login_details l,
                                        user_details w 
                                    WHERE l.UID = q.UID
                                      AND l.UID = w.UID  
                                      AND l.UID = '$UID' ");

 //echo $result;
$json = array();
if($result==false)
{
    die(mysqli_error());
}else
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $json['Details'][]=$row;
        }
    }
}

$json_output1 = json_encode($json);
echo $json_output1;

?>
```

I have database structure like below

**login_details** have filed :UID,username,email,mobilenumber,password,image

**quotes** have filed :quote_id,quote,status,credit,UID,QOD,quote_date

**user_details** have filed :user_details_id,UID,Credit,Withdrawal,Total,Completed

What we are missing ?
Thanks

Comment: We are missing a bunch of your relevant code!!!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have included full code... Please check it. Thanks

Comment: So how are you connecting the `user_details` table to the other tables????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [the `JOIN` keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).  Currently you're listing tables like this:

```
FROM quotes q, login_details l,user_details w
```

Which "works", but performs an implicit join type over which you have no control.  And it would seem that join type is `INNER JOIN`.  The key thing to note with an `INNER JOIN` is that if any given table doesn't have a matching record, the entire result record is omitted.

Instead, it sounds like you want something more like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  The syntax for that would be more like:

```
FROM quotes q
LEFT OUTER JOIN login_details l
  ON q.some_column = l.some_column
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_details w
  ON q.another_column = w.another_column
```

Now, I don't know the columns on which you're joining, so I just put placeholders in there.  But hopefully you get the idea.  Instead of *implicitly* letting the database "figure it out", this syntax allows you to *explicitly* tell the database exactly how to join the tables.

And the key thing about `LEFT OUTER JOIN` here is that, if there's no matching record in the table being joined, the record from the original table is still included.  (Albeit with `NULL` values from the joined table.)

Comment: I have included full file...Can You please edit your answer as per my code ? Thanks

Comment: @AshokSinh: "Edit the answer" how?  Have you attempted what this answer suggests?  Has something failed in some way?

Comment: @ David I do not understood "some_column". Sorry I am new in PHP so not know exactly what You want say. Thanks

Comment: @AshokSinh: Well, I don't know your database structure.  Simply use the column(s) which would be appropriate for joining your tables.

Comment: Please check my Question...I have added Database Structure...Thanks for Your nice help

Comment: @AshokSinh: It looks like the `UID` columns are *probably* the ones you'd use to join the tables.  Please, instead of trying to get Stack Overflow to do all of your work for you, at least read up on the concepts being described here and walk through some basic tutorials on the subject.  Actually understanding the system you're maintaining is going to be far more effective than copying/pasting guesses made by strangers.